# Is there an impact to do not use an activated Attrib?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Should I disable shaders attributes when switching to a program shader which uses less (or different locations of) attributes?

I enable and disable these attributes with glEnableVertexAttribArray()/glDisableVertexAttribArray().

Is there any performance impact, or could it bring some bugs, or doing enable/disable will be slower than activate all attributes and let them activated ?

Comment: If you switch to a different shader program, what do you care for what's bound to the old one? Or is it the same shader program with a different mesh?!

Comment: After some tests, I have noticed that if I enable attributes (0 & 1 for example) for my first shader, after switching to a different shader attributes 0 & 1 will be enabled to this other shader program.

Comment: Yes, vertex setup state, which includes whether a given attribute is enabled/disabled, is not part of the shader program state. This is a good question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OP most likely understands the first part already, but let me just reiterate some points on vertex attributes to set the basis for the more interesting part. I'll assume that all vertex data comes from buffers, and not talk about the case where calls like `glVertexAttrib3f()` are used to set "constant" values for attributes.

- The `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` and `glVertexAttribPointer()` calls specify which vertex attributes are enabled, and describe how the GPU should retrieve their values. This includes their location in memory, how many components they have, their type, stride, etc. I'll call the collected state specified by these calls "vertex attribute state" in the rest of this answer.
- The vertex attribute state is not part of the shader program state. It lives in Vertex Attribute Objects (VAOs), together with some other related state. Therefore, binding a different program changes nothing about the vertex attribute state. Only binding a different VAO does, or of course making one of the calls above.
- Vertex attributes are tied to `attribute`/`in` variables in the vertex shader by setting the location of the `in` variables. This specifies which vertex attribute the value of each `in` variable should come from. The location value is part of the program state.

Based on this, when binding a different program, it is necessary that the locations of the `in` variables are properly set to refer to the desired attribute. As long as the same attribute is always used for the shader, this has to be done only once while building the shader. Beyond that, all the attributes used by the shader have to be enabled with `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`, or by binding a VAO that contains the state.

Now, finally coming to the core of the question: What happens if attributes that are **not used** by the program are enabled?

I believe that having unused attributes enabled is completely legal. At least I've never seen anything in the spec that says otherwise. I just checked again, and still found nothing. Therefore, there will be no bugs resulting from having unused attributes enabled.

Does it hurt performance? The short answer is that it possibly could. Let's look at two hypothetical hardware architectures:

- Architecture A has reading of vertex attribute values baked into the vertex shader code.
- Architecture B has a fixed function unit that reads vertex attribute values. This fixed function unit is controlled by the vertex attribute state, and writes the values into on-chip memory, where vertex shader instances pick them up.

With architecture A, having unused attributes enabled would have no effect at all. They would simply never be read.

With architecture B, the fixed function unit might read the unused attributes. The vertex shader would end up not using them, but they could still be read from main/video memory into on-chip memory. The driver could avoid that by checking which attributes are used by the current shader, and set up the fixed function unit with only those attributes. The downside is that the state setup for the fixed function unit has to be checked/updated every time a new shader is bound, which is otherwise unnecessary. But it prevents reading unused attributes from memory.

Going one step farther, let's say we do end up reading unused attributes from memory. If and how much this hurts is impossible to answer in general. Intuitively, I would expect it to matter very little if the attributes are interleaved, and the unused attributes are in the same cache lines as used attributes. On the other hand, if reading unused attributes causes extra cache misses, it would at least use memory bandwidth, and consume power.

In summary, I don't believe there's a clear and simple answer. Chances are that having unused attributes enabled will not hurt at all, or very little. But I would personally disable them anyway. There is a potential that it might make a difference, and it's very easy to do. Particularly if you use VAOs, you can generally set up the whole vertex attribute state with a single `glBindVertexArray()` call, so enabling/disabling exactly the needed attributes does not require additional API calls.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is clear about how it works. I did not know VAOs, but I will test its usage in order to prevent these possible impacts.